# How to store homemade bread?

Tags: bread, food-preservation

I made a bigger batch of bread than I was initially planning on, and I don't want it to go bad before I get a chance to eat it. Having it go stale isn't an issue (french toast, bread pudding), but having it go moldy is.

What do you consider the best way to store homemade bread?

EDIT: It's a [No knead Sourdough bread](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/knead-not-sourdough-recipe/index.html). I wanted to double the recipe and ended up tripling it.

Comment: What kind of bread is it?

Comment: The recipe you linked isn't **sourdough**. Should it be another link?

Comment: @J.A.I.L. - I'm just going by the recipe title. It does have a slight twang. But yes, you are correct in that it doesn't use a starter.

Comment: @Chris I just wondered because sourdough bread, being sourer is less prone to get mouldy (moulds won't like low pH).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When I make home made bread, I decide how much I'm going to eat in the next day or two and leave that out on the breadboard, usually just covered with a tea towel. I usually put the cut side down on the board to help prevent it from drying out.

The rest gets pre-sliced, put in a zip-top bag, and stashed in the freezer. A few minutes in the toaster oven, and the bread is good as new. Pre-slicing it allows you to just use what you need instead of thawing the whole loaf. It lasts pretty much indefinitely in the freezer.

Comment: I'm going to have to give this a try. It should also keep me from eating half the loaf in one day.

Answer (score 2):

Excess moisture is your enemy; a bit of condensation between loaf and plastic bag is loved by bread-mold. Sliced bread goes faster than whole.

Wrapping in papertowel before bagging is an option but that may also dry out the loaf some. A good bread tin/box is perfect if it is regularly sterilized so that spores don't pounce on new arrivals.